# Can't make a derived instance of MonadTrans for newtype

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following newtype declaration. It is wrapping a Monad stack transformer stacking some standard mtl monads like Reader and Except.

```
newtype TrxDbFileBased f a = TrxDbFileBased {
        unTrxDbFileBased :: ExceptT TrxDbError (ReaderT TrxDbFileBasedEnv f) a
    } deriving (
        Functor
    ,   Applicative
    ,   Monad
    ,   MonadError TrxDbError
    ,   MonadReader TrxDbFileBasedEnv
    ,   MonadIO
    ,   MonadTrans
    )

data TrxDbFileBasedEnv = TrxDbFileBasedEnv {
        workingDirectory :: FilePath    
    } deriving (Show)

data TrxDbError = TrxDbErrorIO TrxDbFileBasedEnv IOException
                | TrxDbErrorStr TrxDbFileBasedEnv String 
                deriving (Show)
```

I want this newtype to be an instance of `MonadTrans` but I am getting the following error.

```
    • Can't make a derived instance of ‘MonadTrans TrxDbFileBased’
        (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
        cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
    • In the newtype declaration for ‘TrxDbFileBased’
   |        
31 |     ,   MonadTrans
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why `MonadTrans` cannot be derived given that the underlying type is `ExceptT` which is an instance of `MonadTrans`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that, if this derivation worked, your instance of `MonadTrans` would be transforming the functor `f`, while the instance for `ExceptT`, which you're expecting to be used as base of derivation, is transforming monad `ReaderT TrxDbFileBasedEnv f`.

These are not representationally equivalent, so `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` can't help you here.

Here's another way to think about it: try implementing the class manually. If you try that, you'll see that your `lift` will have to be defined like this:

```
lift = TrxDbFileBased . lift . lift
```

that is, first lifting `f` into `ReaderT`, then lifting `ReaderT` into `ExceptT`, and then wrapping all of that in `TrxDbFileBased`. But GND expects to do nothing more than the no-op wrapping, which means just straight up reusing the method dictionary, since the types are representationally equivalent. This is not the case in your case.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I just defined `lift` the way you suggested.